# Definition of plurisubharmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, several-complex-variables

Firstly, my definitions, in which this question lies:

> Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. $f:D\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$ is subharmonic if
>
> - $f$ is upper semi-continuous in $U$.
> - For every open ball $B_{2}(a,r)$ (with $a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ y $r\in\mathbb{R}$) such that $\overline{B_{2}(a,r)}\subseteq U$ and for each $g:\overline{B_{2}(a,r)}\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$ continuous function in $\overline{B_{2}(a,r)}$ and harmonic in $B_{2}(a,r)$, such that $f(x)\leq g(x)$, for all $x\in\partial B_{2}(a,b)$, we have $f(x)\leq g(x)$, for all $x\in B_{2}(a,r)$.

> Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a domain (open and connected). $f:D\to \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}$ is plurisubharmonic if:
>
> - $f$ is upper semi-continuous in $D$.
> - $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$,
>   \begin{equation*}
>      \begin{array}{cccc}
>       f_{a,b}:&\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^{2} &\longrightarrow& \mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty\}\\
>       &z&\longmapsto&f(a+bz)
>      \end{array}
>     \end{equation*}
>   is subharmonic in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: a+bz\in D\}$.

My question is rather simple... There is a place on the definition of plurisubharmonic function where I have some doubts...

> Why is $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: a+bz\in D\}$ an open set in $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Any hint/ advice is appreciated... I just don't want to work with this concepts until I understand them as accurately as I can. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $a, b \in \Bbb C^n$ is
$$
 h: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C^n, h(z) = a+bz
$$
a *continuous* function, and
$$
\{z\in\mathbb{C}: a+bz\in D\} = h^{-1}(D)
$$
is open as the preimage of an open set under a continuous function.